# PDO Select with $_POST

Tags: php, pdo

this works just fine

```
$db = new PDO(<connection data>);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = "name";
        $pw = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = ?');
        $pw->execute(array($username));
        $result = $pw->fetchAll();
        var_dump($result);
    }
```

If i use $_POST['username'] after form submission i get array(0) { } for var_dump($result);

```
$db = new PDO(<connection data>);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        //var_dump($username); --> string(7) " name"
        $pw = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = ?');
        $pw->execute(array($username));
        $result = $pw->fetchAll();
        var_dump($result);
    }
```

Do you see where i made my mistake(s)?

Comment: what do you mean by after form submission?

Comment: var_dump shows it, `trim($_POST['username'])` ?

Comment: Since when is the string "name" `7` characters long...?

Answer (score 1):

In the first test, with hard-coded value, you have

```
$username = "name";
```

then, when using post value, it becomes

```
$username = $_POST['username']; // --> " name"
```

as you see, there is an extra space. If such space should not be there, you could then try trimming the value, like:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
```

However, if having spaces in username is an error, you should not "correct" it yourself, and just report the error to the user (I think this is more a UX aspect than a programming one).

Comment: Instead of using `trim`, shouldn't we ask - why that blank space is being added in the first place? ;)

Comment: That is an option too, I just didn't think of it :) I added a clause about it.

Comment: You're still 'curing' the space, not preventing it ;)

Comment: Yes, the edit was only about removing it if you know a priori it should not be there. I think it is quite common practice to trim spaces from username at login form, or at least, I recall that google does so.

Comment: OK! trim() solved the issue. It was a form that came with a theme template, I have not figured out why the space was added. Nevertheless i then built my own and it is working perfectly fine. Thanks